# In C, why this statement- 'i = 5i' compiles & sets 'i' to zero?

Tags: c, language-features

In GCC the following C code compiles correctly-

```
int i = 7;
i = 5i;
printf("%d", i);
```

And prints- `0`.

The statement `i = 5i` clearly makes no sense. Then why on earth the code does not give any compilation error? And why `i` becomes `0`?

Comment: imaginary constants are a GCC extension

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [GCC extension for representing the imaginary component of complex numbers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Complex.html).

The compiler complains if you compile with `-pedantic` and `-Werror`: http://ideone.com/PMlZr5.

Comment: So, here `i` of `5i` is being treated as *imaginary*? If so, then why replacing `i` with `j` also gives same result?

Comment: @MinhasKamal - That's mentioned on the docs page I linked to ;)

Comment: Oh! I missed 'j'!